# Meteor: How to debug meteor methods that require users to log in

Tags: debugging, testing, meteor

I've been using **meteor shell** to quickly test **Meteor methods** and it is very convenient. Is there any way to use it to test the Meteor methods that require a user to log in?

If it can not be done, what is the best practice to test this kind of methods?

Comment: You can just load up your app in a browser and run the method call from the browser console. Any console.log in your method will appear in the terminal running your meteor app

Comment: Fantastic, works like a charm! Thanks @PhilipPryde. Please create an answer using your comment so that I can choose it.

Comment: Done cheers :D  @Yichen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just load up your app in a browser and run the method call from the browser console. Any console.log in your method will appear in the terminal running your Meteor app.

Alternatively you may want to look into using the [velocity](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity) framework for automating tests to avoid having to run them manually.